# Does the ASUS P5G1T-M LX2/GB motherboard support AHCI mode for SSDs?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, bios, ahci

I got an OCZ Vertex 4 SSD the other week and I've managed to install it and it's working, but I think it's still running in SATA mode instead of AHCI mode (which if I understand correctly is more efficient for SSDs). I've had a look in the BIOs and I can't spot anything which sets AHCI mode. I have a nasty suspicion that my motherboard doesn't support it. CrystalDiscInfo says that the transfer mode is SATA/600

**Does anyone know if the ASUSTeK P5G41T-M LX2/GB motherboard supports AHCI mode and if it does, how to set an SSD connected to it to use AHCI mode.**

I am not using this SSD as my main disk, I'm using it as an extra disk for putting some games and other applications on which I want to load more quickly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, AHCI and SATA mode refer to the same thing. Or do you mean IDE instead of SATA?

Comment: @Indrek Wikipeida: ["AHCI is separate from the SATA 3 Gbit/s standard, although it exposes SATA's advanced capabilities."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface)

Comment: @techie007 I know the actual terms stand for different, though related things. What I meant was that most motherboards use SATA and AHCI to refer to the same thing - running a hard drive in native SATA mode, as opposed to emulated IDE mode (see "Operating modes" section in same Wikipedia article). Hence OP's comment about "running in SATA mode instead of AHCI mode" doesn't make sense.

Comment: I've seen plenty of original SATA/3Gb boards that don't provide AHCI.  For the ones that do support it (ie: most current boards), AHCI usually needs to be specifically selected, as you need to be able to go back into legacy/IDE SATA mode for operating systems that don't support AHCI.  AHCI chip-sets need to "emulate" IDE, non-AHCI SATA _is_ IDE already (no emulation needed). :)

Comment: Related; [Why should I choose (or not) AHCI over IDE in my PC's BIOS settings?](http://superuser.com/questions/4020/why-should-i-choose-or-not-ahci-over-ide-in-my-pcs-bios-settings?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can find, that motherboard's chip-set does *not* provide AHCI.

Check for yourself in [the Manual](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=1&s=22&m=P5G41T-M%20LX2/GB&os=29&hashedid=n/a) over at support.asus.com (no mention of AHCI).

Also, there's no drivers provided that relate to AHCI.

Usually a board that provides AHCI also provides basic RAID capabilities, as they are very much related.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you must be right :( . I think I get about half the advertised speed of the SSD. I'm surprised, because the PC is pretty new, it has a quad core CPU and came with 8 GB of RAM, but it was pretty cheap, so they probably cut corners in places like that :(