# Dell XPS 15 9570 - Boot Windows 10 or Ubuntu 20.04 installed on separate drives

Tags: windows, ubuntu, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS 15 9570. I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on a SSD and Windows 10 installed on a nvme SSD. Dell outlines the appropriate BIOS settings to boot Ubuntu [here](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ca/000123462/recommended-bios-settings-for-your-linux-system). Will these settings prevent me from being able to boot Windows 10?

Comment: No probably not. Did you try it? Did you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

Three things in the article you linked

1. ```
   Under the General Section > Boot Sequence, make sure that the dot is selected for UEFI.
   ```

win cannot boot in UEFI mode if you have installed it in legacy mode or vice versa.

You will have to reinstall win in the mode you want {you can covert it too using [mbr2gpt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt) if you don't wanna re-install}

You might face problems like grub not detecting win if win and linux are installed in different FIRMWARE mode

> Most of the linux bootloaders installed for one firmware type cannot
> launch or chainload bootloaders of the other firmware type. That is,
> if Arch is installed in UEFI/GPT or UEFI/MBR mode in one disk and
> Windows is installed in BIOS/MBR mode in another disk, the UEFI
> bootloader used by Arch cannot chainload the BIOS installed Windows in
> the other disk. Similarly if Arch is installed in BIOS/MBR or BIOS/GPT
> mode in one disk and Windows is installed in UEFI/GPT in another disk
> , the BIOS bootloader used by Arch cannot chainload UEFI installed
> Windows in the other disk.

2. ```
   Under the System Configuration Section > SATA Operation, make sure that the dot is selected for AHCI.
   ```

it depends if you change this after installing win/{or any other os} then it will fail to boot

From this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/4125/777184)

> To actually use AHCI, the OS (whether that's Windows, Linux or even
> Ghost) has to have an AHCI driver. Windows Vista and 7 include the
> driver, but don't install it if the boot drive's controller doesn't
> have AHCI enabled. Similarly, the IDE driver doesn't get installed if
> the IDE controller is disabled. That's why you can't just toggle the
> setting in the BIOS on an already installed Windows system.

3. ```
   Under the Secure Boot Section > Secure Boot Enable, make sure that the dot is selected for Disabled.
   ```

Win can boot with this turned on or off. But you might face problem in booting ubuntu

When Secure Boot is active , only signed EFI binaries (e.g. applications, drivers, unified kernel images) can be launched.

For more read [Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface/Secure_Boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface/Secure_Boot)